# Javascript Delete Collection

Tags: javascript, object

So i am trying to loop through a collection and delete all of the records. My code currently looks like this:

```
if (ev.NewStatusName == "Collect Initial Docs") {
var count = ev.File.GetCollectionCount("Condition");
for (var a = 1; a <= count; a++) // loop
{ 
ev.File.DeleteCollectionObject("Condition", a);
}
}
```

But I keep getting this error

[image: enter code here]

Can anyone help with this. It deletes one item and then throws this error like it's not looping though and removing all items.

Comment: Please add `ev` and any other code.

Comment: you need to provide more info, what os? is it in a browser? what is `ev`? what throws the error on the screen....

Comment: what is `ev`? What API is this?